# What is the difference between returning auto&& and decltype(auto)?

Tags: c++, c++14, return-type, forwarding-reference, decltype-auto

I am trying to make template wrapper function, that should forward parameters and return value. And I can't decide what is better to use `auto&&` or `decltype(auto)` for return type. I've read Scott Meyers [article](http://scottmeyers.blogspot.com/2013/07/when-decltype-meets-auto.html) and understood that it is necessary to return `decltype(auto)` compared to `auto` not to strip ref_qualifiers.
As far as I understand the same argument works for using `auto&&` over `auto`.
Now I have following questions:

1. Am I right, that there is no difference between `decltype(auto)` and `auto&&` when we return reference to object?
2. What happens if we return `rvalue` object, like: `return int{};`? Will return value be dangling reference?
3. What is the difference between `decltype(auto)` and `auto&&`? What better fits as forward return type?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> What is the difference between `decltype(auto)` and `auto&&`?

[`decltype(auto)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) covers three cases. When returning lvalues, the return type would be `T&` (lvalue-reference); for xvalues, the return type would be `T&&` (rvalue-reference); for prvalues, the return type would be `T` (non-reference, i.e. return by-value).

`auto&&` covers only two cases. When returning lvalues, the return type would be `T&` (lvalue-reference); for rvalues, including xvalues and prvalues, the return type would be `T&&` (rvalue-reference). ([Forwarding reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references) is always a reference.)

> What happens if we return rvalue object, like: `return int{};`? Will return value be dangling reference?

For `auto&&` the return type is rvalue-reference, so yes, the returned reference is always dangling. For `decltype(auto)` the return type is non-reference then no such trouble.