# How to return by universal reference or by value when needed?

Tags: c++, templates

I tried to reduce my problem to a minimal example

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <utility>

template <typename T> struct some_traits;

template <typename T> using traits = some_traits<std::remove_cvref_t<T>>;

struct reference_struct {
    std::string s;
};

template <> struct some_traits<reference_struct> {
    template <typename T> // T is constrained to reference_struct
    static auto &&get(T &&t) {
        return std::forward<T>(t).s;
    }
};

struct by_value_struct {
    std::string s;
};

template <> struct some_traits<by_value_struct> {
    template <typename T> // T is constrained to by_value_struct
    static auto get(T &&t) {
        return t.s;
    }
};

template <typename T> static auto &&element(T &&t) { return traits<T>::template get(std::forward<T>(t)); }

// overload that returns by value
template <typename T> static auto element(T &&t) { return traits<T>::template get(std::forward<T>(t)); }

int main() {
    reference_struct r;
    by_value_struct b;
    auto &&reference_result = element(r);
    auto by_value_result = element(b);
}
```

In the example, we see `some_traits`, which can be specialized for different structs to implement different static `get` methods.

Then there is a universal global `auto&& element(T&&)` function, where `T` is a struct with `some_traits` implemented (in the actual code `T` is constrained using concepts).

Some structs might implement `some_traits::get` by returning *by reference*, others might return *by value*.

`auto get` is used because the structs can return any type, not just `std::string`.

The above code does not compile, because calls to `get` are ambiguous. If the "overload that returns by value" is not present, there is of course a compiler warning stating that `element` returns a reference to a temporary. I tried specializing:

```cpp
template <> static auto element(by_value_struct&& t) { return traits<by_value_struct>::template get(std::move(t)); }
template <> static auto element(by_value_struct& t) { return traits<by_value_struct>::template get(t); }
template <> static auto element(const by_value_struct& t) { return traits<by_value_struct>::template get(t); }
```

But the template specializations could not be matched due to the return type mismatch (`auto` vs `auto&&`).

My question is, can I create a function with a more general interface, which returns either by universal reference or by value (copy)? I mean in a way the outside user does not have to know beforehand which one will get returned.

Comment: Can't you just have a one `element` function that returns by `decltype(auto)`?

Comment: @Kaldrr That is exactly what I needed, thank you. Although I don't understand how it works.

Comment: It perfectly forwards the return type of the function, as described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69335619/1719926, which also neatly explains why `auto&&` was troublesome here.